# how to get the time difference in cyclistic google data analytics case study using R?

Tags: r

When I run this code

```
all_trips$ride_length <- difftime(all_trips$ended_at,all_trips$started_at)
```

I get the following error

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

I'm a beginner and i seek guidance to understand how to get the time difference in seconds

Comment: Have you converted your vectors `all_trips$ended_at` and `all_trips$started_at` to POSIT (i.e. date-time) format?